# How do i convert this code from v3# to v4#?

Tags: javascript, botframework, azure-bot-service

I find this great code in stackoverflow with version sdk3, but that version has been update to version sdk4.
Does anyone knows how to upgrade that?

I try some things but gave me some erros mainly in header

I find some samples in git but in there i need to use react.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
<script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.js"></script>
   <link href="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js"></script>
    <style>
        #mychat {
            margin: 10px;
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 30px;
            right: 10px;
            z-index: 1000000;
        }
    </style>
</head>

</html>
<script>
    (function () {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
        div.outerHTML = "<div id='botDiv' style='width: 400px; height: 0px; margin:10px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; right:0; z-index: 1000;><div  id='botTitleBar' style='height: 40px; width: 400px; position:fixed; cursor: pointer;'></div></div>";
        BotChat.App({  // change to window.WebChat.renderWebChat
            directLine: { secret: 'myAppSecret' },
            userID: 'YOUR_USER_ID',

        }, document.getElementById("botDiv"));

        document.getElementsByClassName("wc-header")[0].setAttribute("id", "chatbotheader");
        document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            e.target.matches = e.target.matches || e.target.msMatchesSelector;
            if (e.target.matches('#chatbotheader')) {
                var botDiv = document.querySelector('#botDiv');

                botDiv.style.height = "0px";

                document.getElementById("mychat").style.display = "block";
            };
        });

        document.getElementById("mychat").addEventListener("click", function (e) {

            document.getElementById("botDiv").style.height = '500px';

            e.target.style.display = "none";
        })
    }());
</script>
```

Comment: "I find this great code in stackoverflow with version sdk3": this is not SDK v3. Maybe Webchat v3, but not SDK v3, which is referring to the bot sdk, on bot side.

Comment: you are right, can you help me?

Comment: First thing: why do you want to migrate? And... if the referenced script is the ‘latest’ in the cdn, it must be already pointing to v4... so what is your initial need?

Comment: i have already a customized web chatbot in v4 version with some customization in avatar , and i also want to try with this minimizable web chat sample

Comment: @Miguel Moreira I hope you got it working! If you feel my answer was sufficient, please "accept" it so I can clear this ticket from my support tracker. If not, let me know how else I can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code, I would recommend taking a look at this [Minimizable Web Chat Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#migrating-from-web-chat-v3-to-v4). Its a little bit more complicated since it is written in React, but accomplishes what you are trying to do.

If you are still interesting in porting the code in your question to Web Chat, I suggest you take a look at the [Migrating from Web Chat v3 to v4](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#migrating-from-web-chat-v3-to-v4) section in Web Chat's README.

Alternatively, you can add Facebook Messenger as a channel for your bot and use their [Chat Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/customer-chat-plugin/) on your website.

Hope this helps.